# How to watch the logstash log?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

For my enterprise application distributed and structured logging, I use `logstash` for log aggregation and `elastic search` as log storage. I have the clear control pushing logs from my application to logstash. On the other hand, from logstash to elastic search having very thin control.

Assume, if my `elasticsearch` goes down for some stupid reason, The logstash log(`/var/log/logstash/logstash.log`) is recording the reason clearly like the following one.

```
Attempted to send a bulk request to Elasticsearch configured at '["http://localhost:9200/"]', but Elasticsearch appears to be unreachable or down! {:client_config=>{:hosts=>["http://localhost:9200/"], :ssl=>nil, :transport_options=>{:socket_timeout=>0, :request_timeout=>0, :proxy=>nil, :ssl=>{}}, :transport_class=>Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::HTTP::Manticore, :logger=>nil, :tracer=>nil, :reload_connections=>false, :retry_on_failure=>false, :reload_on_failure=>false, :randomize_hosts=>false}, :error_message=>"Connection refused", :class=>"Manticore::SocketException", :level=>:error}
```

How will I get noticed OR notified for the `error` level logs from logstash?

Answer (score 0):

Should be doable with the following 3 steps:

1) Depends on how you want to get notified. If an email is sufficient you could use the Logstash [email output-plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-email.html).
But [there](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/output-plugins.html) are many more output plugins available.

2) To restrict certain events you can do stuff like that in your Logstash config (example is taken from the Elastic support [site](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/using-logstash-how-to-filter-errors-only-from-logs/43234/3)):

```
if [level] == "ERROR" {
  output {
     ...
  }
}
```

The `if` clause is not limited to the level field of your JSON; you are able to apply it for any of your JSON fields of course, which makes it more powerful.

3) To make this work (and not run into a logging cycle) you need either:

- Start a second Logstash instance on your system (just observing the Logstash ERROR log), which should be okay from what is written [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/multiple-logstash-instances-on-single-server/28947)
- Or you build a more complicated configuration, using just one Logstash instance. This configuration has to forward log-statements from YOUR application to Elasitcsearch while logstaments from Logstash ERROR logs are forwarded to the e.g. Logstash email output-plugin.

---

Side note: you may want to have a look at Filebeat which works very well with Logstash (Its from Elastic as well) and it is even more light-weighted than Logstash. It allows stuff like `include_lines: ["^ERR", "^WARN"]` in your configuration.
To receive input from Filebeat you will have to adopt the config to send data to Logstash and for Logstash you will have to active and use the Beats input plugin described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-beats.html).